# Javascript substituição de frases

Tags: javascript

Como poderia substituir frases em uma determinada parte do meu site em intervalos de tempo usando javascript.

Comment: Crie uma lista de textos que você deseja que apareça, defina uma função que exiba um desses textos e faça com que essa função seja executada de tempos em tempos com a `setInterval`. Acredito que com isso você já consegue pelo menos tentar fazer alguma coisa e sair do zero;

Answer (score 0):

Como sugerido pelo [Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss), utilize `setInterval` com uma lista de frases a serem apresentadas. Fiz um fragmento de código para te auxiliar:

```
var frases = ["Frase 1",
              "Frase 2",
              "Frase 3",
              "Frase 4"];
var count = 0;

var changeText = function(){
  if(count <= 3){
    $("#txt").text(frases[count]);
    count++;
  }else{
    count = 0;
  }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(changeText, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Com JavaScript**

Seguindo a orientação do Anderson Carlos Woss, não tem o que errar, veja comentários no código

```js
var i = 0;
var frase = [];

// Crie uma lista de textos que você deseja que apareça
frase[0] = "Como poderia substituir frases";
frase[1] = "em uma determinada parte do meu site";
frase[2] = "em intervalos de tempo";
frase[3] = "usando javascript. ";
frase[4] = "Valeu Anderson Carlos Woss. ";

//defina uma função que exiba um desses textos
function rodarFrases() {
   
   document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = frase[i++];

   if (i >= frase.length)
      i = 0;
      //e faça com que essa função seja executada de tempos em tempos

   setTimeout("rodarFrases()", 3000);  
}

rodarFrases();
```

```html
<div id="texto"></div>
```

**Com Jquery**

```js
(function(){
    var words = [
        'Como poderia substituir frases',
        'em uma determinada parte do meu site',
        'em intervalos de tempo',
        'usando jquery.'
        ], i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#texto').fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).html(words[i=(i+1)%words.length]).fadeIn();
        });
    }, 3000);
        
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span id="texto">Como poderia substituir frases</span>
</div>
```